# How to make Spring Cloud Stream create RabbitMQ queues and binding when the application has no producers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1 and the Spring cloud dependencies are imported from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Finchley.RC1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I believe that the dependencies of interest are these:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

In my `application.yaml` I've added multiple consumer bindings:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input1:
          bindingRoutingKey: key1.#
          binder: rabbit
          group: group1
          destination: dest-group1
          transacted: true
        input2:
          bindingRoutingKey: key2.#
          binder: rabbit
          group: group2
          destination: dest-group2
          transacted: true
```

I've read for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552703/398441) that one should add `requiredGroups` to the producer(s) in order to create the queues and bindings automatically. However my application doesn't produce any messages, it just consumes messages published by other application so I don't have any producers defined. I've tried to modify the `application.yaml` file to just add a dummy producer:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        dummyProducer:
          producer:
            requiredGroups: group1,group2
        input1:
          bindingRoutingKey: key1.#
          binder: rabbit
          group: group1
          destination: dest-group1
          transacted: true
        input2:
          bindingRoutingKey: key2.#
          binder: rabbit
          group: group2
          destination: dest-group2
          transacted: true
```

But this doesn't work. So my question is:

How should I modify my `application.yaml` file (and possible the code if required) to make the Spring Cloud stream create the queues and bindings on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally only provision the exchange on the producer side; we don't provision queues unless `required-groups` is set.

On the consumer side, we always provision queues (and the exchange).

If that is not happening, something else is wrong; do you have `@EnableBinding`?

Show your application code.

Comment: It did indeed work, the problem was that I was expecting this to work when having declared an application.yaml in resources in the src/main/resources folder but the src/test/resources folder was empty. I thought that the tests would pickup the application.yaml from src/main/resources when src/test/resources was empty but this wasn't the case.